# OutOfMemoryError on emulator while reading large txt file

Tags: java, android

I have large txt file wich contains more than 200k lines. Each line 1 word.
I need to load all words from this file, it is working ok on my Nexus 7, but when i try to start my app on emulator i get OutOfMemoryError. Where the problem can be? I want to be sure that phone users will not have such error.

```
    public static ArrayList<String> getWords(Context context) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(300000);

    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("words.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String word;
    while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
        words.add(word.toUpperCase());
    }

    is.close();
    br.close();

    return words;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a database instead? Android devices usually have (very) limited RAM.

Comment: adding the stack trace would help a bit.

Answer (score 3):

It is not advisable to load such a big file in memory as you cannot be sure of hardware resources available on android device.

I would recommend that you use sqlite database instead. It will not only allow you to load the data but also facilitate easy search and modification operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this working in an emulator, you can increase the RAM size.

You can do this when you create the AVD image (there is a "Max VM Application Heap Size" option in the "Hardware" Options).  The default for this value is 24, you will need to put 256 or higher.

This is the solution for you specific issue,  but you think about using a DB instead, as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

200K is relatively big for android device, therefore you must use db.

But I think your problem is something else.
Did you increase emulator memory (device ram size)?